# Having problems using AFNetworking fetching JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking-2, get-request

So i recently wanted to change from using NSUrlConnection to AFNetworking. I can receive the JSON data with both methods buts when using with AFNetworking something weird happens.

**This is how it looks like with NSURLConnection**

[image]

**and this is how it looks like with AFNetworking**
[image]

I have no idea what that (struct __lidb_autoregen_nspair) is and i dont know if that is the thing that is preventing me from displaying the data

This is the code from AFNetworking, i use the sample code from ray

```
-(void) fetchData{

// 1

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// 2
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    // 3
    jsonDict = (NSMutableDictionary *)responseObject;



} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    // 4
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}];

// 5
[operation start];

}
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Edit

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *) getAllGames{

[self fetchData];

DataParser *dataParserObjec = [[DataParser alloc] init];

return [dataParserObjec sendBackAllGames:jsonDict];

}
```

Comment: The `acceptableContentTypes` shouldn't be `application/json`?

Comment: Hmm that could be the problem. When i didint have that line of code sayin text/html i got to the error block. Im guessing that my server is not sending JSON then right?
But why does it work with NSURLConnection?  @Larme

Comment: So the only fix here is to make the server send back json right @rob

Comment: I am able to print it out as you suggested. Now i see the problem but i dont know why its like this. jsonDict is a property in that class and as you see i give the value from responseObject to jsonDict. In another method a little further down i want to send jsonDict but why is value nil for jsonDict? @Rob

Comment: Could it be because its working in the background and the main thread keeps going and as you said im sending an empty Dictionary because it has not finished getting what i need? IF that is so how would i fix this? @Rob

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66030/discussion-between-timo-cengiz-and-rob).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are setting the `acceptableContentTypes` to `text/html`. I presume you are doing that because your web-service is not setting the correct `Content-Type` header to indicate that it's `application/json`. If you fixed the web service to provide the correct header `Content-Type`, you could then remove this `acceptableContentTypes` line in your Objective-C code.

   If you're wondering why you didn't have to worry about that with `NSURLConnection`, that's because `NSURLConnection` doesn't do any validation of `Content-Type` (unless, of course, you write your own code in, for example, `didReceiveResponse`, that checked this).
2. You suggest that you are unable to display the data. But yet there it is, in your second screen snapshot. I personally would be less worried about internal representation than whether I could access the data from the `NSDictionary`. If you

   ```
   NSLog(@"responseObject=%@", responseObject);
   ```

   at #3, inside the success block, what precisely do you see? I'd wager you'll see your `NSDictionary` fine (despite the subtle differences in the internal representation).

   My contention is that you are getting the data back successfully. Yes, your web service should set the correct `Content-Type` header so you don't have to overwrite the `acceptableContentTypes` value, but it looks like AFNetworking is retrieving your data fine.
3. The likely issue is that your main thread is trying to use `jsonDict` before the asynchronous network request is done. So the trick is to defer the use of the `jsonDict` until the asynchronous request is done.

   You've updated your question showing us that you're instantiating a `DataParser` and calling `sendBackAllGames`. You should put that code *inside* the completion block of your asynchronous network request.

   Alternatively, you could use a completion block pattern in your `fetchData` method, and then the `getAllGames` method could supply the `sendBackAllGames` code in a completion block that `fetchData` calls inside the success block of the `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

---

If you used the completion block pattern, it would look like

```
-(void) fetchDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(id responseObject, NSError *error))completionHandler {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    // removed once we fixed the `Content-Type` header on server
    //
    // operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(responseObject, nil);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                    message:[error localizedDescription]
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(nil, error);
        }
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

And you'd call it like so:

```
[self fetchDataWithCompletionHandler:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (responseObject) {
        DataParser *dataParserObjec = [[DataParser alloc] init];

        NSMutableDictionary *results = [dataParserObjec sendBackAllGames:jsonDict];

        // do whatever you want with results
    }
}];
```

If the method that called `getAllGames` needed the data to be returned, you'd repeat this completion block pattern for this method, too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280648/afnetworking-sending-nsmutabledictionary-as-post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307814/label-in-uitableviewcell-not-changing-the-first-time-its-loaded

I have had this problem for a while and i could never solve it. u seem to know much maybe you have a clue about why i am having this problem @Rob