# AFNetworking sending NSMutableDictionary as POST

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2, http-post

Im new to using AFNetworking. I managed to make GET request work with some help from a nice guy here in stack overflow.

Now im stuck in making a POST request. I try this code but i always end up in failed block. How come?

```
-(void) postEventInfo: (NSMutableDictionary *) eventInfoObject{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:string parameters:eventInfoObject success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    //here is place for code executed in success case

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {


    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error while sending POST"
                                                        message:@"Sorry, try again."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
 }
```

i get the following error message:

> **Error: Request failed: internal server error (500)**

Thnx..

**EDIT1**

OK so after testing a little bit more i noticed that the connection actually goes through and inte does what i want to do but it still shows me the error message meaning still going to the fail block.

I THINK my server is sending back text/html could it be something to do with that?

the part were NSURLConnection worked

**EDIT2**

```
    NSError *error;
NSData *event = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:eventInfoObject
                                                options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                  error:&error];

if (! event) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:event];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[event length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [conn start];
}
```

Comment: Your server crashed.

Comment: But why. it works fine when i send it using Normal NSURLConnection @Andy

Comment: You send application/json right?

Comment: Yes, Do i need to say that in the code? @Andy

Comment: RequestSerializer should do that

Comment: OK, the `NSURLConnection` code helps eliminate some possible problems. (BTW, please refer to the documentation for `-[NSURLConnection start]`, which makes it clear that you should _only_ call `start` if you use `initWithRequest` with the `startImmediately` option set to `NO`: in this case, you should remove `start` call.) At this point, you really need to use something like Charles to find out what's differ by in the two requests.

Comment: OKay good to know that in the future if i would use NSURLConnection.
I know i want to use charles and i tried many things but nothing seems to be wokring. I cant get it to catch my requests... @Rob i even installed the SSL certificate to simulators

Comment: The website that im trying to get my JSON data from is run on localhost:5000 so it has nothing to do with my ip address @Rob

Comment: But that wont solve my issue?
I am getting my JSON from localhost:5000 when i enter my own ip address to web browser i end up somewhere else.
Are we talking about the string in XCODE or Charles now? @Rob

Comment: @TimoCengiz Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66233/discussion-between-rob-and-timo-cengiz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is not setting `Content-Type` header of `application/json` (or something equivalent), `AFHTTPSessionManager` will fail. You could theoretically jury-rig the AFNetworking `acceptableContentTypes` value, but better than that, you should just fix the server code to return the appropriate `Content-Type` header.

But if your server is responding with a 500 code, then you have some more fundamental problem, one that we can't possibly solve without more information about the server (e.g. code, some details about the implementation, etc.).

If you have a working `NSURLConnection` example, I'd be inclined to run both that code, as well as the above code, and observe the requests via [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com). Look carefully at differences in the requests, and the problem will probably jump out at you.

Comment: Thanks for Charles! i will use it and look it up

Comment: I think i actually managed to change so that the server sends application/json instead. How i knew because going to the url i can see that the text font changed.

I downloaded Charles but i cant seem to make it display the requests that is being made from the simulator. I saw some tutorials where i have to manually put the proxy and port but my IOS simulator dont have a wifi tab that i can press on? How could i fix this @Rob

Comment: I am starting it before the simulator. But if you check your simulator and try to find the wifi tab to choose the proxies and ports. You wont find it. I dont know where to configure the settings if the simulator dont have the wireless tab @Rob

Comment: I don't know what you mean about this wifi tab. I've never seen that nor ever done anything with that. Bottom line, if http (i.e. non SSL), you don't have to do anything. If doing SSL, go to "Proxy" - "Proxy Settings..." and click on the SSL tab.

Comment: Looked up using Charles. I saw that the post message was sent and the type was html/text. Watched my server code and saw that i forgot to change on some parts where it sends back information. So some places sent back application/json and some parts html/text, changing it all to application/json fixed the problem. Thnx!! <3 @Rob

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that with AFNetworking you set base URL for your HTTP manager e.g

```
http://api.example.com/
```

But then when you post requests you use endpoint (path relative to base URL) instead of absolute URL, e.g

```
[manager POST:@"users/add" ...
```

Which AFNetworking automatically  transforms into absolute URL behind the stage:

```
http://api.example.com/users/add
```

This is clearly done for convenience of building API clients, that's why POST, GET and other methods take string argument instead of NSURL.

In your particular case changing

```
[manager POST:string ...
```

to

```
[manager POST:@"/" ...
```

Should efficiently fix the problem.

Comment: Did not work :(, The post method still works and my data is getting posted and updates but the alert view is still showing @Andy